# Angular 5 app (click) not working on Safari

Tags: angular, typescript, mobile-safari

I made a simple angular 5 app adding  chessboardjs and jquery libs.
It works perfectly in chrome and firefox (desktop and mobile)
On Safari (IOs) however the (click) event is not fired at all. Even through that the app renders and connects to the server without problem.
I am not sure if there is a know issue or how can I make this work.

```
<div (click)="onDivClick()"> Click me </div>
```

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular_ios_safari",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.13",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@qontu/ngx-inline-editor": "^0.2.0-alpha.12",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "chess.js": "^0.10.2",
    "chessboardjs": "0.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.21.0",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.6",
    "@types/moment-duration-format": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any other div on top of this one?

Comment: Can you repro your code in StackBlitz?

Comment: Pleas add your `package.json` - I met this situation, when I add library for force click support on iOS.